# transitioning multiple elements with d3

Tags: d3.js, transition

I'm having a heck of a time with transitions in D3js.  I posted a fiddle here: [dynamic area graph](http://jsfiddle.net/yHrYs/4/).  The problem that I run into is that when trying to follow this tutorial [path transitions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), I run into sync problems with the xAxis. Bostock indicates that the domain should be skewed slightly so that the data appears to "shift" in from the side.  However, when I do that, the data reflected will be listed under a tick mark that is "2 minutes" behind the actual time it should be listed.  If I just update the data as-is, without doing the tricky stuff with the clip-path, it works fine.  All of the data is in sync.  Just for reference, the xAxis is an integer, linear scale.  Dealing with date strings was madding, even though d3 has great time manipulation, I just find dealing with epoch easier.  If someone could check out the fiddle and let me know how to transition the entire drawing...I want it to be smooth like in the examples that bostock has.

Since SO requires *some code*, here's the data structure that I'm generating.  The rest is in the fiddle:

```
    setInterval(function(){
  lastTime = lastTime.add('m',1);
  var data = {"apikey":"FOO",
    "description":"a dumb description",
    "beg_effective_dt_tm":lastTime,
    "data":{
      "sum":getRandomInt(385,4000),
      }
    };
    tick(data);
},1000)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you do have a solution that works (without the clip path)?

Comment: the enter-update-exit pattern successfully works on the data, but it doesn't do it using transition(), which i'd like to add to make it smooth. I can't seem to make that part work correctly when I skew the data to hide it behind the clip path.  When doing so, the data plots are offset from the x-axis and reflect incorrect time to data correlation.

Comment: So if you don't use a clip path it works?

Comment: negative. clip or not, the data still skews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is close to what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ7Rj/1/
It is close because the graph is delayed by one value.

Most of the architecture was already there, and your concern that you might lose the *sync* between the `xAxis` and the `data` was correct. Mike gets around it by changing his `range` of the scales. The other (and better, IMO) way is to do it by changing the domains. I made the following two primary changes.

#### The domain of the axis

I have modified the `minMax` function such that it does not include the latest and the last point in the domain of the `xAxis`. Note that this means that the most recent value (as well as the oldest value) is actually displayed outside the visible region. This is an unfortunate limitation of using the `monotone` interpolation, which Mike talks about at the bottom of his post.

```
function minMax(pd) {
  return [
      d3.min(pd.slice(1).slice(0, -1),function(d){ return d.beg_effective_dt_tm; }),
      d3.max(pd.slice(1).slice(0, -1),function(d){ return d.beg_effective_dt_tm; })
    ];
}
```

If you want to have all the values visible, then you'll get the *wiggling* effect of the discontinuous tangent suddenly forming when the new value comes in. You can obtain that by removing the `.slice(0, -1)`.

#### The initial `transform`

For each element, I have initially placed the DOM element *one step* to the right.

```js
var step = x(newVal.beg_effective_dt_tm) - x(pd[pd.length - 1].beg_effective_dt_tm);
// ...
           .attr("transform", 'translate(' + step + ')');
// ...
```

Then finally, I have transitioned everything back to their rightful place:

```js
    clipPath.selectAll("path,circle,.dp").transition()
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ",0)");
```

Also, I have enabled the transition for the `xAxis`.

Comment: That's a great way to think about it.  It is definitely easier to conceptualize!  I noticed that you were transforming each element, and I was doing ".attr("transform", null);". Looks like i had a few things wrong.  thanks for the suggestions!  I just applied this to several other time series graphs that I made and they are no longer suffering from the same problem.

Comment: Using `.attr('transform', null)` should also do the same thing as setting it to `translate(0, 0)`. I prefer the explicit version. Glad to have helped. :)